# Spring Integration AWS - S3 Inbound Adapter Deliver the read files to Output Channel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

we are having a use case to deliver the read files from s3 inbound Adapter to a output channel (not to a local dir and read using file-inbound), where we will process the file. Please let me know how we can achieve this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it isn't possible as an out-of-the-box feature and that would be implemented as a part of `<int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway>`. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-60 for tracking.

Meanwhile you can simply implement some custom `<service-activator>` and operate with the `AmazonS3.getObject()` directly.